# subversion does not store the password

Tags: svn

Whenever I use subversion, it asks for a password, I type yes to store, but the same does not store, does anyone know how to fix this? When this message appears:

```
can only be stored to disk unencrypted! You are advised to configure your system so that Subversion can store passwords encrypted, if possible. See the documentation for details. You can avoid future appearances of this warning by setting the value of the 'store-plaintext-passwords' option to either 'yes' or 'no' in '/root/.subversion/servers'.
```

Comment: English please otherwise 90+% of AskUbuntu can not help